Need a Cosmos query to find records by value without a key
I am storing data in a Cosmos db which looks similar to the example shown below. I need to write a query that will look in the “payload” section to see if a value exists. It is not possible to use the key (eg 'lastModifiedOn.previousValue') as these are dynamically created.
{
    "externalId": null,
    "serviceName": "Test.Api",
    "payload": {
        "enabled.previousValue": "False",
        "enabled.currentValue": "True",
        "lastModifiedOn.previousValue": "2024-04-15 11:24:28",
        "lastModifiedOn.currentValue": "2024-04-15 11:24:28"
    },
    "actionType": "Modified"
}

I have used the following query but it fails to find any records. I had hoped it would find records where the supplied datetime exists as a value in the payload section.
SELECT VALUE root FROM root WHERE (ARRAY_CONTAINS(root["payload"]["values"], "2024-04-15 11:24:28") )

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

1: you have no property named root so you can’t select it - you’d need to select root.propertyName or just *; and 2: you don’t have any array types - you just have nested properties.

You can use the IS_DEFINED and IS_NULL, but if you don't know the property name of what you want to check, I don't think this is possible.
But what you can do is to set the serialization option to not write the default values in you json. Like this, if the payload is empty, it won't be present in the jsons, and you can easilly extract them with WHERE NOT IS_DEFINED(c.payload)


Need a Cosmos query to find records by value without a key

To find records by value without using its key is possible by using UDF in Azure Cosmos DB. Below is the UDF which searches the doc without using the key. In UDF x searches with the value provided in the query and provides the required output successfully as shown below.
SELECT * FROM c
WHERE udf.findValueInDocument(c, "2024-04-15 11:24:28")

UDF:
function findValueInDocument(doc, x) {
    for (let key in doc) {
        if (typeof doc[key] === 'object' && doc[key] !== null) {
            const result = findValueInDocument(doc[key], x);
            if (result) {
                return true;
            }
        } else if (doc[key] === x) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

Output:
[
    {
        "externalId": null,
        "serviceName": "Test.Api",
        "payload": {
            "enabled.previousValue": "False",
            "enabled.currentValue": "True",
            "lastModifiedOn.previousValue": "2024-04-15 11:24:28",
            "lastModifiedOn.currentValue": "2024-04-15 11:24:28"
        },
        "actionType": "Modified"
    }
]

